# How to make a wolf angry at a nearby player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am in 1.14 and I want to summon in wolves that are angry.  `summon wolf ~ ~ ~ {Angry:1}` Doesn't work, since the wolf must have a specific player to be angry at, which is stored in UUID's I believe.  This behavior is unlike Zombie Pigmen, which when set angry become agro at all players.  I thought about detecting if a player gets near a wolf, say within 10 blocks, that wolf automatically becomes hostile to that specific player.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who a wolf is angry at is not saved in its NBT. I've created this bug report for it now: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-155036

But you can still do what you want to do, because wolves **really** don't like snowball fights.
Let's say the player who should be attacked has the tag "attackMe", just to have something to differentiate them. Then you can summon a snowball above the wolf and make that snowball pretend to have been thrown by that player:

```
execute at @e[type=wolf] run summon snowball ~ ~2 ~
execute at @e[type=wolf] run data modify entity @e[type=snowball,sort=nearest,limit=1] owner.L set from entity @p[tag=attackMe] UUIDLeast
execute at @e[type=wolf] run data modify entity @e[type=snowball,sort=nearest,limit=1] owner.M set from entity @p[tag=attackMe] UUIDMost
```

Of course you'll probably narrow the selector `@e[type=wolf]` further, currently this system makes every wolf in the loaded area angry at you.